# Changed Target .NET Framework in Visual Studio creates errors

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I was originally writing my program for .NET 4.0... however, recently I changed the target framework for .NET 3.5... the program still works fine, but now I'm running into a rather odd error. In the past, when I built the program, it would generate the .exe and that is it. Now it generates a .exe and a .exe.config.

Should still be fine right? Nope, in the .exe.config file, it has the following code:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        ...
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

As you can see, it says `Version=4.0.0.0` and because of this, when I run the program I get an unhandled exception assembly error. Its pretty easy to fix, I just delete the .exe.config file and all is well. But its starting to become a pain, to do this on each and every build.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you manually inspected the csproj files looking for 4.0 references? There may be some lingering elements you need to manually update.

Comment: _ for using abusive words.. Removed.....

Comment: Switching from 4.0 to 3.5 does not create an app.config; you probably always had one (or added it manually)--which means the .exe.config was always there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it solve your problem. I have found a some how similar question and its answer is here

> Found the answer, delete app.config.
>
> app.config is automatically created based on settings.settings. Visual
>   Studio was not building it, even though it needed to be updated.
>
> Note: Clean and rebuild doesn't force visual studio to clean and
>   rebuild it
>
> Deleting it, to force Visual Studio to rebuild, it fixed it.

Here it is [Visual Studio 2010: Properties.Settings broken after retargetting project to .NET Framework 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141424/visual-studio-2010-properties-settings-broken-after-retargetting-project-to-ne)